# Using C# brackets without function or class syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm new to C# and I can't find the right things to search for. I'm trying to understand the difference between these three types of syntax:

1. `public string Topic(){}`
2. `public class Topic{}`
3. `public string Topic{}`

I know the 1st is a function and the 2nd is a class, but what confuses me is what the 3rd is.

## question

what is `#3` called and how is it used?

Anything that could provide clarity please.

Comment: It's a public property [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) check the first example.

Comment: The third one is a property. It's generally accompanied by a `get` block and a `set` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd is a property. The most common representation in C# is autogenerated properties, like this:

```
public string Topic { get; set; }
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
private string _topic;

public string Topic
{
    get { return _topic; }
    set { _topic = value; }
}
```

It should be used to hold internal states of the object.

It can be a readonly property, with getter only:

```
public string Topic { get; }
```

Or only with setter:

```
public string Topic { set; }
```

You can also apply accessibility modificators in getters and setters, for example:

```
public string Topic { protected get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The third is a property, when used correctly.  It's basically a variable with built in getter and setter.

```
public string Topic {get; set;}
```

This automatically creates a string variable which allows you to set or get directly via Topic = "new topic"

```
public string Topic {get; private set; }
```

allows public access to read the value but only the local class can set it.

Often, when more complexity is required than simply setting/getting, they are used with another backing value:

```
string _topic;
public string Topic { 
    get { return _topic; }
    set { _topic = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The third one is a property in C#. For example, you can have a person object (read class) with few properties. To get and set values for those properties, you use this kind of syntax.

```
public class Person
    {
        private string _name = "";

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name {
            get{
                return "Jonathan";
            }
            set{
                this._name = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here Person has two properties namely Id and Name. The property syntax for Id is using "Automatic Property" syntax, which means someone can get and set this property like this:

```
var person = new Person();
person.Id = "1";//set Id value
//Or get Id value like this
var personId = person.Id;
```

The Name property is being set explicitly. When you request it, the hard coded value "Jonathan" will be returned and when setting, whatever value is assigned, will be set.

You can read more about properties here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The third forms a property function. It lives inside of a class. For example:

```
 public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

To find out more you should look up encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorthand:

This is getting and setting automatically, which is why they are called Auto-Implemented Properties. These two defined properties below are one & the same.

```
 public class Constituent{

   public string Name {get; set;} //This is a property, 

   public string Name //This is a property, The value can only be of type **string** because we've assigned it that datatype, which would also be the return type.
   {
     get { return _name; }
     set { _name = value; }
     }
   }
```

You can also use access modifiers private, public, protected on them. 
This will determine Whether you can you get & set the property value.

```
 public string Name {get; private set; }
```

In order to be be able to access the property you need to instantiate the Class(Constituent). 
An example of how you can instantiate would be:

```
 var constituent = new Constituent();
 constituent.Name = "Jonathon"; //Setting the value of Name property.
 var Member_Name = constituent.Name; //Storing a value into a variable
```

Hope this Helped you. [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: is value a key word or can I change that to whatever naming I'd like?

Comment: The value can only be of type **string** because we've assigned it that datatype, which would also be the return type.

Comment: it is  a keyword.